# Send mass email - timeout exception

Tags: laravel-4, queue

I'm trying to send multiple emails with queues (beanstalkd). My application sends some number of emails and then I receive timeout exception.

```
    foreach ($emails as $e) {
        Mail::queue('emails.invite', ["username" => Auth::user()->username, "grupa" => $naziv, "id" => $id, "email" => $e], function($message) use ($e){        
            $message->to($e)->subject("Pridruži nam se!");
        });
    }
```

Is there a way to put all emails to queue, so when system is available the email should be sent.

EDIT: Full message for timeout exception:

```
{"error":{"type":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException","message":"Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded","file":"\/home\/forge\/default\/vendor\/nikic\/php-parser\/lib\/PHPParser\/NodeAbstract.php","line":110}}
```

Comment: Please post the exact exception you are getting.

Comment: @Bogdan I edited my question and included full error message

Answer (score 1):

How are you doing it? If you're using beanstalk (or any queue), you're doing stuff from your application (producer, send to the queue) and from the worker process that consumes data from the queue and sends the email.

The producer just puts the email into beanstalk, so easy...

The consumer should be a long running process and it should be executed from cli, with no maximum time execution (you have to tweak the php.ini of php-cli). In the loop, you should check if there's something new in the queue and send the email.

Basically, sounds like your problem is that the consumer part has maximum execution time set, so it can't consume the emails in a while loop after X seconds. Tweak that and make sure there's no limit.

Comment: Yes I'm using beanstalk. It shouldn't take so long to send email using queue.

Comment: If the process is a long running one (let's say with a while(true)) then after 30 seconds it will simply crash, of course... How is your consumer written?

Comment: Thanks for your help, I started using MailChimp for this and it's working ok.